# One jQuery selector does work the other not.?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a list of folders and files, the folders have the class `folder` and the files got the class `file`.
When I select those with a live jquery selector '.on("click").

The one where I select the folder works, when I try it by the one of file it wont. Any idea?

jQuery:

```
$("#browser").on("click", ".file", function() {
    alert();
});
$("#browser").on("click", ".folder", function() {
    alert();
});
```

HTML:

```
<li href="<?= $_POST['dir'] ?>/<?= $item ?>" class="list-group-item file">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file pull-left"></i>&nbsp;<?= $item ?>
</li>
<li href="<?= $_POST['dir'] ?>/<?= $item ?>" class="list-group-item folder">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close pull-left"></i>&nbsp;<?= $item ?>
</li>
```